# Add column with filename wildcard

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have files that have the pattern

```
XXXX____________030621_120933_D.csv
YYYY____________030621_120933_E.csv
ZZZZ____________030621_120933_F.csv
```

I am using glob.glob and for loop to parse each file to pandas to create Data frame of which i will merge at the end.  I want to add a column which will add the XXXX,YYYY, and ZZZZ to each data frame accordingly

I can create the column called ID with df['ID'] and want to pick the value from the filenames. is the easiest way to grab that from the filename when reading the CSV and processing via pd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file names are as what you have presented, then use this code:

```
dir_path = #path to your directory

file_paths = glob.glob(dir_path + '*.csv')
result = pd.DataFrame()
for file_ in file_paths :
   df = pd.read_csv(file_)
   df['ID'] = file_[<index of the ID>]
   result = result.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

Finding the right index might take a bit of time, but that should do it.